# Magento 2 visual swatch not working from changing attribute from drop down?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, color-swatches

I have created an attribute "color" with **drop-down**, now as per our customer request we have changed to **visual swatch**.
and did re-index and flush.

but color not displaying at front end as we expected.

AdminEnd Settings:-

[image]

Fronted:-

[image]

Could you please suggest.

Magento 2 version:- **2.2.3 CE**

Thanks

Comment: I Have Tested in the same scenario which you have mentioned above, i was getting the right solution.

Comment: can you please provide me the settings which you have followed?

Comment: Hello @Nagaraju kasa Please find the below link for admin attribute setting screen shot.  https://prnt.sc/kaw39l  and frontend screen shot. https://prnt.sc/kaw4e1